# Ayuda con Angular 9 y new promise

Tags: angular, promesas

**NO logro que funcione**

Intento hacer funcionar una nueva promesa en Angular 9 como
 funcionaba en angular 8, desde que actualice angular, no volvió a
 funcionar como esperaba.> Mi angular instalado

```
             Angular CLI: 9.1.6
             Node: 14.2.0
             OS: win32 x64

             Angular: 10.0.0-next.7
             ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
             ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
             ... router
             Ivy Workspace: Yes

             Package                           Version
             -----------------------------------------------------------
             @angular-devkit/architect         0.901.6
             @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.6
             @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.6
             @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.6
             @angular-devkit/core              9.1.6
             @angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.6
             @angular/cdk                      9.2.3
             @angular/cli                      9.1.6
             @angular/fire                     6.0.0
             @angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.31
             @angular/material                 9.2.1
             @ngtools/webpack                  9.1.6
             @schematics/angular               9.1.6
             @schematics/update                0.901.6
             rxjs                              6.5.5
             typescript                        3.8.3
             webpack                           4.42.0


           I case you need more info
               "compilerOptions": {
                 "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
                 "sourceMap": true,
                 "declaration": false,
                 "moduleResolution": "node",
                 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                 "experimentalDecorators": true,
                 "target": "es5",
                 "typeRoots": [
                   "node_modules/@types"
                 ],
                 "lib": [
                   "es2017",
                   "es2016",
                   "es2015",
                   "dom"
                 ]
               },



             function asyncFileExists(path: string) {
               return new Promise(function (res, rej) { fs.access(path, s.constants.F_OK, function (err) { err ? 
              rej(err) : res(true); }); });
             } 

             @Injectable({
               providedIn: 'root'
             })
             export class InitInfoService {

             }  

             async func1() {
                 let dat:any;

                 console.log('func1');

                   this.ufb.get_datos_administrador().then((datos: dministrador)  {
                     dat = datos;
                     if (!datos[0]) {
                       this.initVarsTmp()
                     } else {
                       this.glo.idAdmin = datos[0].ID;
                       this.glo.dniAdmin = datos[0].DNI;
                       this.titAdmin.setStateAdmInternet(true);
                       this.titAdmin.setNombreToolbar(datos[0].NOMBRE);
                     }
                     console.log(dat);
                   }) 
               }   

             async initOptiones() {
                 this.glo.idAdmin = 0;

                 console.log('init aca');
                 var locError = await syncFileExists(path.resolve('DBCONS.FDB')); <== here is called
                 if (!locError) {
                   console.log('File:' + locError);
                   this.initVarsTmp();
                   this.glo.idAdmin = -11; // error en db  
                 } else {
                   await this.func1();
                   await this.func2();
                   await this.func3();
                 }
```

Esto veo en  console.log

> ```
>  init aca
>       AAA
>       BBB
>       CCC
>       func1
> ```

Esperaba esto

> ```
>     init aca
>      func 1            
>      AAA
>      BBB
>      CCC
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**La solución:**
 Elimine node_modules, luego npm install y todo comenzó a funcionar bien.

Answer (score 0):

El probelma que tienes es que estas usando una version de nodejs que no es compatible con Angular 9.

Puedes hacer un downgrade en nodejs 10.13.x/12.11.x

Te dejo un link con la referencia de Angular, nodejs y typescript

ref => https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3